# Using Model->find('all') returns an array with the following structure

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I moved a website (cakephp 2.1) from a test server ( PHP verson 5.3.10 ) to the live server (PHP verson 5.3.17).
In the new situate all my code started to complaine about undefined
indexes. When debugging an array I see that the array indexes became
numbers instead of the Model names!? What can be the problem of that I
use the exact same installation of cakephp?

Below the 2 examples of arrays.

### this is how the array should be.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Post] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 152
                    [menu_item_id] => 1
                )

        )
```

### This is the array on the live server

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 152
                    [menu_item_id] => 1

                )

        )
```

Comment: Are you sure that configuration of PHP are identical on both servers ? Maybe you get the same waring on all of them, but live server has different level of `error _reporting` set .

Comment: problem solve ... need to upgrade PHP version ( like 5.4 )